# How to bind datasource of amq:SerialChart to filenames in isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, charts, isolatedstorage

I need to bind the names and date of creation of some specific files in isolated storage with datasource  of amq:SerialChart. (windows phone 7.8)
I tried making a view model for this.

```
 public class MainViewModel
{
     public MainViewModel()
    {
         var appStorage =  IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        var items = new List<ChartItemViewModel>();
        string[] fileName = appStorage.GetFileNames("issue*");
         foreach( string file in fileName)
         {
              items.Add(new ChartItemViewModel { Month =file, Value=appStorage.GetCreationTime(file).ToString()});
         }

        var chart = new ChartViewModel { Items = items };

        this.Charts = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 5).Select(_ => chart).ToList();
    }

    public List<ChartViewModel> Charts { get; set; }
}
}
```

but I am getting exception when I run this. The xaml code for the same is

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="Line">
        <amq:SerialChart Style="{StaticResource chartStyle}" 
                         DataSource="{Binding Charts[0].Items}" 
                         CategoryValueMemberPath="Month">
            <amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
                <amq:LineGraph ValueMemberPath="Value" Title="Test Chart" />
            </amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
        </amq:SerialChart>
    </controls:PivotItem>
```